# Kendo UI Grid View implementation using vue | pageable functionality issue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement Kendo grid for my **vue** project and I was trying to show the pagination with items per page option with a custom message like "**Rows per page**"

[image]

Kendo provides a pageable option to show the custom message for these labels, But for some reason even after adding the custom text, I don't see the change in the UI.

Here is my code :

```
<Grid
      :id="tableId"
      :data-items="items"
      :sortable="true"
      :resizable="resizable"
      :columns="displayedColumns"
      :sort="sort"
      :pageable="pageable"
    >
<Grid>

 computed: {
    pageable() {
      return {
        buttonCount: 5,
        info: true,
        type: 'numeric',
        pageSizes: [5, 10, 25, 50],
        previousNext: true,
        pageSizeValue: this.pageSizeValue,
        messages:{
          itemsPerPage: 'rows per page',
        }
      };
    },
 }
```

Am I missing something? Can someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried and spend some time to help you but looks like `pageable.messages` is not supported by kendo grid vue. It is working fine with Javascript version of Kendo grid.

Comment: I too tried with the JS version and it worked, I will see if I can raise the same question in the kendo forum and update this question if I find any solution.

Comment: Yeah please raise. That will be the great if we get the response from Kendo team itself.